# Text crawl in cycles, but text is dark

Tags: cycles-render-engine, text-object

I am pretty new to blender, but I have created a text crawl akin to the star wars crawl. I think I have everything right except for the text color. I have selected a really bright yellow, however when it is rendered it appears dark. Is there a way to make the text shadeless like you can in blenderrender or is there another way to achieve a brighter color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing Alt-C to convert your text to a mesh object. I have found Cycles doesn't render text properly as text objects, as opposed to meshes. You could also try this shadeless material: [image]

This should make your text be exactly the color you had picked without affecting any other objects in your scene.

Comment: A .blend file would also help.

Comment: thankyou both for your answers I am new to this and getting your head round the interface is one helluva challenge. I am currently rendering and this should be finished in a couple hours so I will upload my blend from that tomorrow. Loving this community it so helpful, would be lost without it!

Answer (score 1):

Just give it an Emission Shader (instead of the default Diffuse one) with a Strength of 1.0.

Comment: I had a play around with that to no avail, even boosted it to 50 and there seemed to be no change

Comment: think ive nailed it! for whatever reason i didnt pick up on this before, but i have two materials in the blend and ive been fiddling with the one that isnt relevant to the text. I dont even know why there is a second material ho peculiar! - there is however a small box on the line of 'a new start' to the left of it which will not go, do you know how I can remove that

Comment: So if this answer helped you out after you solved your preventing problem, don't forget to upvote or mark as answered.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/attempt1_1 hi Samoth, could you take a look at my blend and see if it looks right, also do you know of a way I can remove the box to the left at the start of the crawl?